# How to make margin at all sides in mat-card-image?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular7

I am new for web development and in below code I want to make margin to my image at all sides, but it's not working. What mistake did I make?

### css

```
.example-card {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.main-image{
  margin:10px;
}

.example-header-image {
  background-image: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

### html

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image class="main-image" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
      The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
      A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
      bred for hunting.
    </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1ce7h?file=app%2Fcard-fancy-example.html

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.main-image{
  margin:10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: how can we apply top and bottom margin as well

Comment: [Reference Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

You can also use the shorthand property: 

`p {
  margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
}`

• top margin is 25px
• right margin is 50px
• bottom margin is 75px
• left margin is 100px

`p {
  margin: 25px 50px;
}`

• top and bottom margins are 25px
• right and left margins are 50px

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to the `img` to *restrict it horizontally* and then you can *centralize* it using auto margins:

```
.main-image{
    margin: 10px auto; /* 10px top & bottom, auto for left and right */
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [`updated stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1ce7h-utmzwx?file=app/card-fancy-example.css).

But I would suggest to use `box-sizing: border-box` and then apply the *space* by using `padding` - as `mat-card-image` already has +100% width set and setting *negative margins* for the *layout-ing*.

```
.main-image{
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See [`updated stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1ce7h-id5hmr?file=app/card-fancy-example.css).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="image">
<img mat-card-image class="main-image" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
</div>

.image {
  margin:20px;
}
.mat-card-image {
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-image {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

add the width in .main-image class so this way your image would be inside the card with the all sides margins

and also adds the box-sizing in example class

```
.example-card {
    max-width: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margin is perfectly working just fine. You have given width to .mat-card-image more than 100% which overflows the parent container.

Currently it's this:

```
.mat-card-image{
  width: calc(100% + 32px);
}
```

It's more than 100% width of the container so it's supposed to go beyond the parent container. Also if you are using flex property i would suggest you to do this to get it aligned correctly:-

```
.example-card{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.mat-card-image{
  width: 100%;
}
```